# Django - change form field to readonly when value in view is set to any value

Tags: django, django-forms

In my view.py I have a variable - for example 'email'. In my forms.py I have an email field - for example:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label="Email adress")
```

I would like to change this to:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label="Email adress", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
```

when email variable from my view.py is filled (from None to any value). By default email is set to None. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Form` `init()` to set the attributes:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Either pass as kwarg form = MyForm(email='some@email.com')
    email = kwargs.get('email', None)
    # Or as initial value form = MyForm(initial={'email': 'some@email.com'})
    email = self.fields['email'].initial

    if email is not None:
        self.fields['email'].attrs.update({'readonly': 'readonly'})
        # or you could potentially do this, depending on what you're trying to achieve
        self.fields['email'].disabled = True
```