# Django Forms - How to make certain fields readonly except for superuser

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I use `UserChangeForm` and `UpdateView`, to update user information the `UpdateView` is only accessible for the owner of the account and `superuser`. now, I need to make the `username` and `subject` fields to be read only when the owner wants to edit their profile info but it will be editable when `superuser` access wants to edit it.

**forms.py**

```
class TeacherUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    readonly = ("username", "subject")
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "phonenumber", "address", "subject"]

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(TeacherUpdateForm, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        for x in self.readonly:
            self.fields[x].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'

    def clean(self):
        data = super(TeacherUpdateForm, self).clean()
        for x in self.readonly:
            data[x] = getattr(self.instance, x)
        return data
```

**views.py**

```
class TeacherUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = TeacherUpdateForm
    template_name = "account/update_form.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["user_type"] = "Teacher"
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(TeacherUpdateView, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if obj.id is self.request.user.id or self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return obj
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied()
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse("index"))
```

I feel stuck because every solution I see is using `get_readonly_fields` and it doesn't work on the `forms` or `views`. For another info, the `subject` field is a `foreignkey` from another model.

so far I can make those field `readonly` for the owner but it still `readonly` as well for `superuser`, I want to make it `editable` for `superuser` but not for the owner

Comment: Have you tried using the __init__ on TeacherUpdateForm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219452/django-change-form-field-to-readonly-when-value-in-view-is-set-to-any-value.

Comment: @MarcCompte doesn't work

Comment: And have you tried with attrs["readonly"] instead of attrs["disabled"]? Another thing you can try is using disabled as a widget object property, not as an attr dict key: i.e. widget.disabled = True. According to the docs it looks like it should work if you can have the request user there.

Comment: yeah the 'readonly' works, iirc I can use the request user inside `__init__` ?, i dont know how to make it.

Comment: For that you'll probably have to override the get_form() in your view. There, you can add a kwargs['request'] that will be available in your init. In your init you may have to remove this kwarg before calling the super().init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forms.py**

```
class TeacherUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "phonenumber", "address", "subject"]
```

**views.py**

```
class TeacherUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = TeacherUpdateForm
    template_name = "account/update_form.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["user_type"] = "Teacher"
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(TeacherUpdateView, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        # Restrict type of user who can access UpdateView
        if obj.id is self.request.user.id or self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return obj
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied()

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(TeacherUpdateForm, self).get_form(form_class)
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            # Disable these fields
            form.fields["username"].disabled = True
            form.fields["subject"].disabled = True
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse("index"))
```